# Smarty variable in controller to a tpl

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop

I created a smarty variable to a controller (`OrderController.php`).
The customer select a value and his choice is in this variable. This work perfectly.

Now, I want to use this variable (value) in my back office (`tpl` file) to display the value. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

In ordercontroller.php

$smarty->assign("myvar", $myvar); // this assigns the variable to smarty.

Now in your tpl file that you want to display this variable use the syntax.

{$myvar} and it will display the contents of your variable.

Comment: I have an error :
[8] Undefined index: choix_magasin

[8] Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: My assign in ordercontroller.php : $smarty->assign('choix_magasin',$resultat); and in the .tpl (_shipping.tpl of back office) : {$choix_magasin}

Comment: try to debug the array values inside tpl. {$choix_magasin|@print_r} i think there is no value at index 8